# pg_waldump: command not found

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

According [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgwaldump.html) I can use pg_waldump for display a human-readable rendering of the write-ahead log of a PostgreSQL database cluster.

I have clean installation of PostgreSQL-11 server on Ubuntu 18.04, but I have not this command:

> pg_waldump: command not found

Below list of present pg utilites:

```
pg_archivecleanup    pg_conftool          pg_dumpall           pg_recvlogical       pg_virtualenv
pg_basebackup        pg_createcluster     pg_isready           pg_renamecluster     
pg_buildext          pg_ctlcluster        pg_lsclusters        pg_restore           
pg_config            pg_dropcluster       pg_receivewal        pg_updatedicts       
pg_config.libpq-dev  pg_dump              pg_receivexlog       pg_upgradecluster
```

What I need to do for use this command on my server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not in the default `PATH`, so you'll have to invoke it with its absolute path:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_waldump <WAL file name>
```